# How to get the page count of a microsoft word document in java?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ms-word

for a server based j2ee application, I need to retrieve the number of pages from word documents.. any ideas what works?

Answer (score 3):

If the documents are modern Word 2007 format you can use direct XML-based manipulation, through [OOXML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338205.aspx#office2007aboutnewfileformat_developingsolutionsusingtheoffice). This is by far the better long term solution, though I realize it may not be realistic for an entire organization to change overnight.

If they are older Word formats, you're probably stuck with server-side Word/Excel/Powerpoint/Outlook programmable object models, although [you're not supposed to do that on the server](http://blogs.technet.com/tristank/archive/2008/11/06/don-t-use-office-applications-or-gdi-or-system-drawing-or-wininet-in-a-server-application-or-asp-net.aspx)..

Answer (score 3):

Regarding Office Open XML support, the latest beta of [Java-POI](http://poi.apache.org/index.html) is supposed to support it.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't used it before but you could try [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/). Looks like it has a [WordCount](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hpsf/SummaryInformation.html#getWordCount()) function.

Answer (score 0):

//Open the Word Document

```
Document doc = new Document("C:\\Temp\\file.doc");
```

//Get page count

```
int pageCount = doc.getPageCount();
```

Answer (score 0):

To read the page count of MS Office files you can use aspose libraries (aspose-words, aspose-cells, aspose-slides).

Examples:

Excel: 
number of pages of the printable version of the Woorkbook:

```
   import com.aspose.cells.*;
   public int getPageCount(String filePath) throws Exception {
        Workbook book = new Workbook(filePath);
        ImageOrPrintOptions imageOrPrintOptions = new ImageOrPrintOptions();
//        Default       0   Prints all pages.
//        IgnoreBlank   1   Don't print the pages which the cells are blank.
//        IgnoreStyle   2   Don't print the pages which cells only contain styles.
        imageOrPrintOptions.setPrintingPage(PrintingPageType.IGNORE_STYLE);

        int pageCount = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < book.getWorksheets().getCount(); i++) {
            Worksheet sheet = book.getWorksheets().get(i);

            PageSetup pageSetup = sheet.getPageSetup();

            pageSetup.setOrientation(PageOrientationType.PORTRAIT);

            pageSetup.setPaperSize(PaperSizeType.PAPER_LETTER);

            pageSetup.setTopMarginInch(1);
            pageSetup.setBottomMarginInch(1);
            pageSetup.setRightMarginInch(1);
            pageSetup.setLeftMarginInch(1);

            SheetRender sheetRender = new SheetRender(sheet, imageOrPrintOptions);

            int sheetPageCount = sheetRender.getPageCount();
            pageCount += sheetPageCount;
        }
        return pageCount;
    }
```

Word: number of pages:

```
import com.aspose.words.Document;
public int getPageCount(String filePath) throws Exception {
     Document document = new Document(filePath);
     return document.getPageCount();
 }
```

PowerPoint: number of slides:

```
import com.aspose.slides.*;
public int getPageCount(String filePath) throws Exception {
     Presentation presentation = new Presentation(filePath);
     return presentation.getSlides().toArray().length;
 }
```